# Can I uninstall one in Visual Studio 2013 and VS2013 with update 5?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[My Computer Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG28J.png)

My computer have two visual studio like picture below:

[image]

Can I uninstall one of its? Because my disk is almost full. Please help me, I am very confused about this. Thanks so much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have added the image for you.

Comment: Rohit Gupta: Thanks so much..so I would like to ask that can i uninstall Visual Studio 2013 in second row on picture?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't use Visual Studio, it is hard to know.  But judging from the space it uses up.  I would say yes.  Remove the "Visual Studio Ultimate (2013).  Leave the Update 5 intact.

If it doesn't work then just reinstall it.  It won't affect your existing projects etc.